# Adding a preview pane to my form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that I'm working on that lets the user pick a file with a file browser.  Once the file is picked, I'd like to have a preview panel on my form show a preview image of the file that was selected.  The file will always be a Microsoft Word Document.  Does anyone have an example or know of a site that explains how to do this?  Thanks so much!

EDIT:  Here's my code, so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an instance of the Open File Dialog Box
        var openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        // Set filter options and filter index
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Word Documents (.docx)|*.docx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;

        // Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialog box.
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        txtDocument.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

    }
```

I'd like to add a preview pane to this form so that after the file is selected, it will show a graphic preview of the file.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [View Data Your Way With Our Managed Preview Handler Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163487.aspx) to get an idea of how to display a preview of a file.

Updated link for this article in a blog:

[Blog - View Data Your Way With Our Managed Preview Handler Framework](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmagazine/2007/01/04/vista-and-office-view-data-your-way-with-our-managed-preview-handler-framework/)

Comment: Whoah!  That looks like what I need.  As soon as the timer is up, I'll mark this as the answer.  Thanks so much!

Comment: the link gets me to a site with lots of msdn magazines. Any change you could tell me in which magazine I have to be to find this answer ?

Comment: @KarlAnderson Thanks

Comment: This is the current link to the magazine article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/january/windows-vista-and-office-writing-your-own-preview-handlers